# Como puedo recorrer una array de diccionarios en flask

Tags: python, array, formularios, flask, diccionarios

tengo mi siguiente código python y lo que tengo que hacer es imprimir todos los datos en un documento html, pero no se ni donde comenzar, tengo una array que contiene diccionarios con las reservas, lo que hago es mediante el formulario recojo los datos y luego los añado a la array.

```
TotesReserves=[]
titolsCol=['','Dilluns','Dimarts','Dimecres','Dijous','Divendres']
titolsFilera=['15:00','16:00','17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00']

@app.route('/procesar', methods=['POST'])
def procesar():
    dia = request.form.get('dia')
    hora = request.form.get('hora')
    tipo_de_pista = request.form.get('tipopista')
    nombre = request.form.get('nom')
    telefono = request.form.get('telefon')
    #Creamos la nueva reserva (diccionario)
    reservaNueva = {"Nombre":nombre, "Telefono":telefono, "tipopista":tipo_de_pista, "dia":dia, "hora":hora}
    #Guardamos en "TotesReserves"
    TotesReserves.append(reservaNueva)
    return render_template("reservas.html",dades=TotesReserves,fil=titolsFilera,col=titolsCol)
```

Aqui dejo la parte donde introducir los datos, por cada diccionario, me tienes que imprimir el nombre, el telefono... las keys basicamente, pero no se como hacerlo.

```
{% for valor in dades %}
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dia</td>
      <th scope="row">Aqui iria el dia</th>       
      <td>Hora</td>
      <th scope="row">Aqui la hora</th>
      <td>Tipus</td>
      <th scope="row">el tipo de pista</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Usuari</td>
      <th scope="row" colspan="3">Nombre</th> 
       <td>Telefon</td>
      <th scope="row">aqui el telefono</th>       
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://www.mattcrampton.com/blog/iterating_over_a_dict_in_a_jinja_template/

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.